# React Native: Element Type is Invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I'm doing an online React Native course, and when following along I get a set of errors that the instructor doesn't when trying to render my `ListingEditScreen` component. I checked all my imports and exports, as well as for any syntax errors or misspellings but I've been debugging for hours and can't figure out why it's complaining. Your help is much appreciated.

The errors are as follows:

> ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `ListingEditScreen`. This error is located at:
> in ListingEditScreen (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `ListingEditScreen`.
> This error is located at:
> in Formik (created by AppForm)
> in AppForm (created by ListingEditScreen)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by Screen)
> in RCTSafeAreaView (created by Screen)
> in Screen (created by ListingEditScreen)
> in ListingEditScreen (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)

This is my `ListingEditScreen.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import {
  AppForm as Form,
  AppFormField as FormField,
  AppFormPicker as Picker,
  SubmitButton,
} from "../components/forms";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  title: Yup.string().required().min(1).label("Title"),
  price: Yup.number().required().min(1).max(10000).label("Price"),
  description: Yup.string().label("Description"),
  category: Yup.object().required().nullable().label("Category"),
});

const categories = [
  { label: "Furniture", value: 1 },
  { label: "Clothing", value: 2 },
  { label: "Camera", value: 3 },
];

function ListingEditScreen() {
  return (
    <Screen style={styles.container}>
      <Form
        initialValues={{
          title: "",
          price: "",
          description: "",
          category: null,
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        <FormField maxLength={255} name="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <FormField
          keyboardType="numeric"
          maxLength={8}
          name="price"
          placeholder="Price"
        />
        <Picker items={categories} name="category" placeholder="Category" />
        <FormField
          maxLength={255}
          multiline
          name="description"
          numberOfLines={3}
          placeholder="Description"
        />
        <SubmitButton title="Post" />
      </Form>
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default ListingEditScreen;
```

This is my `AppForm.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";

function AppForm({ initialValues, onSubmit, validationSchema, children }) {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      {() => <>{children}</>}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default AppForm;
```

This is my `app.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ListingEditScreen from "./app/screens/ListingEditScreen";

export default function App() {
  return <ListingEditScreen />;
}
```

Comment: Did you run `yarn` / `npm install` and `pod install` after adding the dependency?